# Doesn`t appear all the intents of the agent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have a DialogFlow agent with the default intents and also intents "Registrar" and "explicacion-funcionamiento" but none of these appears on Actions on Google. It only shows the defaults. I put some photos.

Although I'm using the Dialogflow integration, I need Actions on Google to access the basic information of the user (I need the email).

What can I do?

This is my dialogflow agent:

[image]

This is the actions builder:

[image]

If the user is not logged in, I will redirect him to the "explicacion-funcionamiento" but if he is signed in, he can access to "registrar" intent.
That 's why i need this intent.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Dialogflow and Actions Builder are two different tools. While you can make a Dialogflow agent that works with Actions on Google, you won't be using the Actions Builder. Are these two different Google projects? Can you update your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do, or what you've done so far to get to this point?

Comment: Well, when you use DialogFlow there is a button in integrations to call Actions on Google (you can see the proyect). The actions on Google offers the option to do the sign in, that's why i need it. I will clarify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Actions Builder to use Dialogflow with Actions on Google, or even to use Account Linking. Dialogflow's integration with Actions on Google can still be done using the Actions Console, but the Actions Builder screens aren't available.

The pages for [Account Linking with Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/identity) are still available, and most previous questions in StackOverflow still reference how to do this with Dialogflow.

Keep in mind that there are tradeoffs between using Dialogflow and Actions Builder - but Account Linking is supported equally well in both.

If you do wish to switch to Actions Builder (and to get new features, you'll need to do so), there is (currently) no way to automatically convert from one to the other.

Comment: I would love to convert from one to the other. How can i do it? Thanks!